# Can't deploy Next.js app to Vercel. What I can do?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, deployment, vercel

I have Next.js project that works properly in localhost but when I trying deploy to Vercel I ran into problem

Here is errors that I got.

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: @wagmi/core@2.6.3
npm ERR! Found: viem@1.19.13
npm ERR! node_modules/viem
npm ERR!   viem@"^1.19.13" from the root project
npm ERR!   viem@"^1.0.0" from @safe-global/safe-apps-sdk@8.1.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/@safe-global/safe-apps-sdk
npm ERR!     @safe-global/safe-apps-sdk@"^8.1.0" from @safe-global/safe-apps-provider@0.18.1
npm ERR!     node_modules/@safe-global/safe-apps-provider
npm ERR!       @safe-global/safe-apps-provider@"0.18.1" from @wagmi/connectors@4.1.12
npm ERR!       node_modules/@wagmi/connectors
npm ERR!         @wagmi/connectors@"4.1.12" from wagmi@2.5.5
npm ERR!         node_modules/wagmi
npm ERR!     @safe-global/safe-apps-sdk@"8.1.0" from @wagmi/connectors@4.1.12
npm ERR!     node_modules/@wagmi/connectors
npm ERR!       @wagmi/connectors@"4.1.12" from wagmi@2.5.5
npm ERR!       node_modules/wagmi
npm ERR!         wagmi@"^2.5.5" from the root project
npm ERR!   2 more (@web3modal/wagmi, mipd)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer viem@"2.x" from @wagmi/core@2.6.3
npm ERR! node_modules/@wagmi/core
npm ERR!   peer @wagmi/core@"2.6.3" from @wagmi/connectors@4.1.12
npm ERR!   node_modules/@wagmi/connectors
npm ERR!     @wagmi/connectors@"4.1.12" from wagmi@2.5.5
npm ERR!     node_modules/wagmi
npm ERR!       wagmi@"^2.5.5" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer @wagmi/core@">=1" from @web3modal/wagmi@3.4.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/@web3modal/wagmi
npm ERR!     @web3modal/wagmi@"^3.4.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   1 more (wagmi)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: viem@2.7.6
npm ERR! node_modules/viem
npm ERR!   peer viem@"2.x" from @wagmi/core@2.6.3
npm ERR!   node_modules/@wagmi/core
npm ERR!     peer @wagmi/core@"2.6.3" from @wagmi/connectors@4.1.12
npm ERR!     node_modules/@wagmi/connectors
npm ERR!       @wagmi/connectors@"4.1.12" from wagmi@2.5.5
npm ERR!       node_modules/wagmi
npm ERR!         wagmi@"^2.5.5" from the root project
npm ERR!     peer @wagmi/core@">=1" from @web3modal/wagmi@3.4.0
npm ERR!     node_modules/@web3modal/wagmi
npm ERR!       @web3modal/wagmi@"^3.4.0" from the root project
npm ERR!     1 more (wagmi)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! For a full report see:
npm ERR! /vercel/.npm/_logs/2024-02-06T23_20_49_017Z-eresolve-report.txt
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /vercel/.npm/_logs/2024-02-06T23_20_49_017Z-debug-0.log
Error: Command "npm install" exited with 1
```

Maybe `npm install` can solve this problem or something, but I don't know how to run it in a project in Vercel. Please help me improve this error

Answer (score 0):

Go into the Vercel settings menu for your project. Then in the general settings tab you should find the Build & Development Settings. Override the install command with `npm install --legacy-peer-deps`. Keep in mind that this solution doesn't guarantee success and if the problem persists you should try resolving these dependency issues manually.

Comment: When I add your command to Vercel previous error is gone, but now I got error `Failed to compile.
Attempted import error: 'getProof' is not exported from 'viem/actions' (imported as 'viem_getProof').
Attempted import error: 'withTimeout' is not exported from 'viem' (imported as 'withTimeout').
Attempted import error: 'withRetry' is not exported from 'viem' (imported as 'withRetry').
Error: Command "npm run build" exited with 1 `

Comment: It seems there is a dependency issue within your application

Comment: How I can fix this issue in my apllication?